# insert row having auto increment column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My table is having ID column which is primary key and auto incremented,
i'm trying to insert a row using java (jdbc) like this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/ikpems","root","system");
            Statement st1=con1.createStatement();
            st1.execute("insert into energymetersdata values('20_lab5a_daicel_20_kwh','06-02-2017 12:02:13','8422587','1','42772501540.0694')");
```

But i'm getting errors:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
```

Can any one please help me how to insert this..

Comment: When using `insert`, you should *always* list all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `insert`, you should *always* list all columns explicitly (unless you really know what you are doing):

```
insert into energymetersdata(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    values('20_lab5a_daicel_20_kwh', '06-02-2017 12:02:13', '8422587', '1', '42772501540.0694')");
```

You should also put your date times in ISO standard format and there is no need to quote numeric values going into numeric columns:

```
insert into energymetersdata(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    values('20_lab5a_daicel_20_kwh', '2016-02-06 12:02:13', 8422587, 1, 42772501540.0694)");
```

Finally, you *can* do what you want, even though I strongly discourage it:

```
insert into energymetersdata
    values(DEFAULT, '20_lab5a_daicel_20_kwh', '2016-02-06 12:02:13', 8422587, 1, 42772501540.0694)");
```

But the right approach is:

- List the columns you are inserting.
- Format date/time values so they are unambiguous.
- Keep the types of the constants similar to the types of the columns.

Comment: i tried this query inserted for the first time,when i tried to execute 2nd time                                                                                st1.execute("insert into energymetersdata values('"+Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS+"','20_lab5a_daicel_20_kwh','06-02-2017 12:02:13','8422587','1','42772501540.0694')");   i'm getting this error:                                                            java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'ID' at row 1

Comment: @Praveenreddy if your ID column is an IDENTITY column exclude it from the column list and insert values. The database will allocate a value for that column automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your Query_String like

```
String Query_String = "INSERT INTO tablename(field1,field2) VALUES ('"+Text1+"','"+Text2+"')";
```

Comment: Downvote for posting solutions that are vulnerable to SQL injection. Always parameterize your SQL, concatenation is evil!